# [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout

Tags: wine, amd-graphics, gpu, gpu-driver, amdgpu

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1kJ7M.jpg)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZ3RX.jpg)

I usually have the problem of resetting GPU in directx 11 and directx 12 supported games with wine. How can I solve this problem? Can you help me please?

lspci -k | grep -A 3 -E "(VGA|3D)":

```
2d:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT] (rev ca)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Navi 10 [Radeon RX 5600 OEM/5600 XT / 5700/5700 XT]
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

dmesg:

```
[    9.900810] rfkill: input handler disabled
[   10.863896] r8169 0000:2a:00.0 enp42s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[   13.322903] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
[   13.323716] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 4895748 usecs
[   13.323778] Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
[   13.340719] Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 16558 usecs
[   13.340956] bluetooth hci0: firmware: direct-loading firmware intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
[   13.340969] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-20-1-3.ddc
[   13.349564] Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
[   13.354565] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.3 build 144 week 11 2023
[   13.358058] bridge: filtering via arp/ip/ip6tables is no longer available by default. Update your scripts to load br_netfilter if you need this.
[   13.364574] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI LE Coded PHY feature bit is set, but its usage is not supported.
[   13.557622] kauditd_printk_skb: 25 callbacks suppressed
[   13.557624] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.039:37): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/bin/lxc-start" pid=2105 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.568666] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.051:38): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default" pid=2109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.568671] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.051:39): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-cgns" pid=2109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.568674] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.051:40): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-mounting" pid=2109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.568676] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.051:41): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-container-default-with-nesting" pid=2109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.568679] audit: type=1400 audit(1699353676.051:42): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="lxc-waydroid" pid=2109 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.623766] Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
[   13.626897] NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
[   13.643370] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   13.643376] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   13.643380] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  204.313113] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:2011.000A: HID++ 1.0 device connected.
[  208.045388] systemd-journald[402]: /var/log/journal/314d40c54e9c445387454d023819cee2/user-1000.journal: Journal file uses a different sequence number ID, rotating.
[  208.462602] rfkill: input handler enabled
[  210.015144] rfkill: input handler disabled
[  213.312964] warning: `nspr-2' uses wireless extensions which will stop working for Wi-Fi 7 hardware; use nl80211
[ 1356.466274] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* ring gfx_0.0.0 timeout, signaled seq=1552686, emitted seq=1552688
[ 1356.466639] [drm:amdgpu_job_timedout [amdgpu]] *ERROR* Process information: process CivilizationVI. pid 3855 thread dxvk-submit pid 3934
[ 1356.466971] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset begin!
[ 1356.617473] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: BACO reset
[ 1358.778917] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset succeeded, trying to resume
[ 1358.779073] [drm] PCIE GART of 512M enabled (table at 0x0000008000300000).
[ 1358.779137] [drm] VRAM is lost due to GPU reset!
[ 1358.779138] [drm] PSP is resuming...
[ 1358.825947] [drm] reserve 0x900000 from 0x817d000000 for PSP TMR
[ 1358.869402] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: RAS: optional ras ta ucode is not available
[ 1358.875524] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: RAP: optional rap ta ucode is not available
[ 1358.875526] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: SECUREDISPLAY: securedisplay ta ucode is not available
[ 1358.875528] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
[ 1358.875565] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: use vbios provided pptable
[ 1358.875567] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: smc_dpm_info table revision(format.content): 4.5
[ 1358.878527] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
[ 1359.014579] [drm] kiq ring mec 2 pipe 1 q 0
[ 1359.016510] [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
[ 1359.016663] [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
[ 1359.016676] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx_0.0.0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
[ 1359.016678] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
[ 1359.016679] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
[ 1359.016681] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
[ 1359.016682] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
[ 1359.016684] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[ 1359.016685] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[ 1359.016686] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[ 1359.016688] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[ 1359.016689] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_0.2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[ 1359.016691] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 12 on hub 0
[ 1359.016692] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma1 uses VM inv eng 13 on hub 0
[ 1359.016693] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 8
[ 1359.016695] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 8
[ 1359.016696] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 8
[ 1359.016698] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 8
[ 1359.019299] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow start
[ 1359.021794] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: recover vram bo from shadow done
[ 1359.021823] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021829] amdgpu 0000:2d:00.0: amdgpu: GPU reset(2) succeeded!
[ 1359.021838] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021839] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021843] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021845] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021848] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021851] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021853] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021856] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021862] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021868] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021874] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021883] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021888] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021893] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021897] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021902] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021907] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021912] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021916] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.021921] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.241007] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1359.276333] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.276387] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.765371] gnome-shell[2461]: segfault at 4 ip 00007ff079edc560 sp 00007ffdefaea190 error 6 in libX11.so.6.4.0[7ff079ed8000+8d000] likely on CPU 0 (core 0, socket 0)
[ 1359.765388] Code: 48 89 44 24 18 48 8b 87 68 09 00 00 48 85 c0 74 02 ff 10 ba 18 00 00 00 be 12 00 00 00 4c 89 f7 e8 65 d2 ff ff 44 8b 4c 24 68 <44> 89 78 04 48 89 c1 89 58 08 44 89 68 0c 44 88 60 01 45 85 c9 0f
[ 1359.813860] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.813872] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.813903] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.813931] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.813974] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.813993] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814015] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814043] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814071] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814094] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814114] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814136] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814159] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814188] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814200] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814230] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814257] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814263] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814287] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814300] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814322] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814344] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814367] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814386] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814404] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814515] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814715] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814729] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814747] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814767] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814787] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814900] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814922] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814928] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814950] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814971] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814976] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.814996] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815005] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815014] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815024] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815045] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815069] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815091] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815103] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815124] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1359.815145] [drm] Skip scheduling IBs!
[ 1360.783374] rfkill: input handler disabled
[ 1369.678246] rfkill: input handler enabled
[ 1371.598381] rfkill: input handler disabled
```

I tried to add the command "amdgpu.dcdebugmask = 0x10" into the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT, but it was not successful.